# How to add condtion inside curly brace in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have variable called `$scope.carname = "Volvo"` and in html i need to check `carname` is exist or not if exist that time i need to show link otherwise i need to show some hard coded value(`test`)

Below is my code

Html

```
 <h1>{{carname ? <a href='link'>Go here </a> : test}}
```

controller

`$scope.carname = "Volvo"`;

`$scope.link= "https://www.w3schools.com"`

[Here Is link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/15362/)

Comment: `{{}}` is only for text. Use `ng-if`, see docs

Comment: you can do this in controller.

Comment: help me on this @UshmaJoshi

Answer (score 0):

Use to use two `ng-if` expressions

```
<h1 ng-if="carname"> <a  href='link'>Go here </a>  </h1>
<h1 ng-if="!carname"> {{test}} </h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `ng-if`

```
 $scope.test ="123"
 $scope.carname = "Volvo";
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-if="carname !== ''">{{test}}</div>
    <div ng-if="carname === ''">hard coded value</div>
```

plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/0KBOPuiYsXmYNQfo

Comment: single if can we get this ??

Comment: @komal i think you should use two ng-if, here you have plunker with the solution to your problem : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GtUE3mZwOKiSXjXM